# PHP behaves weird, mixing up HTML markup

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

Thanks for looking on this problem.

I have a page that is totally valid page, and there is a PHP loop that brings in a `<li>` for each entry of the table.

When i check this page locally it looks 100% OK, but when veiwing the page online the left side bar (which creates this markup is broken randomly mixing `<div>`'s and `<li>`'s and i have no clue what the problem is.

This problem is on FF mac and PC (safari looks good)

[See page](http://thepenline.com/penLine/productsLive.php)   (problem is on the left side)

#### php code

```
<?php do { ?>
    <li class="clear-block" id="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['penSKU']; ?>">
      <a title="Click to view the <?php echo $row_Recordset1['penName']; ?> collection" rel="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['penSKU']; ?>">
         <img src="prodImages/small/<?php echo $row_Recordset1['penSKU']; ?>.png" alt="" />
           <div class="prodInfoCntnr">     
                <div class="basicInfo">
                 <span class="prodName"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['penName']; ?></span> 
                 <span class="prodSku"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['penSKU']; ?></span>
                 </div>
                 <div class="secondaryInfo">
                 <span>As low as .<?php echo $row_Recordset1['price25000']; ?>¢ <!--<em>(R)</em>--></span>
                     <div class="colorPlacholder"  rel="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['penColors']; ?>"></div>
                </div>
           </div>
           <div class="additPenInfo">
               <div class="imprintInfo"><span>Imprint area: </span><?php echo $row_Recordset1['imprintArea']; ?></div>
            <div class="colorInfo"><span>Available in: </span><?php echo $row_Recordset1['penColors']; ?></div>
            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                  <tr>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                    <th>500</th>
                    <th>1,000</th>
                    <th>2,500</th>
                    <th>5,000</th>
                    <th>10,000</th>
                    <th>20,000</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                   <td>Price <span>(R)</span></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['price500'];?>¢</td>
                    <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['price1000'];?>¢</td>
                    <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['price2500'];?>¢</td>
                    <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['price5000'];?>¢</td>
                    <td>Please Contact</td>
                    <td>Please Contact</td>
                  </tr>
</table>
           </div>
    </a>
   </li>
        <?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>
```

Comment: The page you linked looks fine to me. Can you clarify what the problem is?

Comment: on the left sidebar, his pens are all borked. he has a bunch of blank entries etc.

Comment: @ waiwai933 Please check it on firefox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot put a `<div>` inside of `<a>`.

Divs are block level elements. Anchors are not. Basically, it's like putting `<span>` outside of `<div>`. Doesn't make any sense.

Solution: Move the anchors to inside the divs.

(In the future, if different browsers are displaying it differently, it's probably not the PHP but the HTML.)

Comment: So why the page does look good locally (localhost)?  on the same browser?

Comment: @adardesign If your PHP code is not being executed on localhost, then that could be the cause of why it's working properly on locally. However, there are too many variables for me to know why for sure without having access to the computer you're using.

Comment: it is being executed on localhost. everything loos good there in all browsers.
Thanks anyway.